# GetNetworkType in Android 11

Tags: telephonymanager, android-11

Following the changes posted [here](https://developer.android.com/preview), the getNetworkType method is deprecated from Android R and onwards.

When trying to use this method in a R compiled application, results in the following exception being thrown:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: getDataNetworkTypeForSubscriber: uid 10225 does not have android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE.
  at android.os.Parcel.createExceptionOrNull(Parcel.java:2285)
  at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:2269)
  at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2252)
  at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2194)
  at com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephony$Stub$Proxy.getNetworkTypeForSubscriber(ITelephony.java:7565)
  at android.telephony.TelephonyManager.getNetworkType(TelephonyManager.java:2964)
  at android.telephony.TelephonyManager.getNetworkType(TelephonyManager.java:2928)
  at com.ironsource.environment.ConnectivityService.getCellularNetworkType(ConnectivityService.java:197)
  at com.ironsource.sdk.service.DeviceData.updateWithConnectionInfo(DeviceData.java:98)
  at com.ironsource.sdk.service.DeviceData.fetchMutableData(DeviceData.java:54)
  at com.ironsource.sdk.service.TokenService.collectDataFromDevice(TokenService.java:120)
  at com.ironsource.sdk.service.TokenService.getRawToken(TokenService.java:177)
  at com.ironsource.sdk.service.TokenService.getToken(TokenService.java:166)
  at com.ironsource.sdk.IronSourceNetwork.getToken(IronSourceNetwork.java:183)
```

This is fine and is expected according to the documentation. If I compile the application to any version before Android R, the exception doesn't show.

This exception indicates that I need to request the [android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#READ_PHONE_STATE) permission.

I wanted to know if there is a way to get the network type with any other API that does NOT require this permission (as this permission's level is dangerous and I would rather not ask the user for it).

Answer (score 2):

Take runtime permission for READ_PHONE_STATE to ignore crash of **getDataNetworkTypeForSubscriber**

```
 @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {

            int res = checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE);
            if (res != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                requestPermissions(new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE}, 123);
            }

        }
    }

    private final static int REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS = 1002;

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS:
                if (grantResults[0] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "READ_PHONE_STATE Denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                } else {
                }
                stepAfterSplash();

                break;
            default:
                super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can still use getDataNetworkType(); This method does not necessarily need READ_PHONE_STATE, as stated in his Doc, but that it's sufficient "that the calling app has carrier privileges".

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager#getDataNetworkType()

For what I know about getting those privigileges, it could be tricky/really hard, you may look into getting carrier privileges and using this method, which is also the suggested substitution for getNetworkType().

Comment: I have obviously read this, but having the application have carrier privileges is not something that is easy to come by (like you stated). So, this isn't really that helpful. ..

Answer (score 1):

This method necessarily need READ_PHONE_STATE by this way in your activity not just manifest >>>

```
// Check if the READ_PHONE_STATE permission is already available.


if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                    Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE)) {

                  //here >> use getNetworkType() method
              // like this example
 
              mStationInfo.set_networkType(mTelephonyManager.getNetworkType());
            } 
           else {}
```

Comment: If you read my question, you will notice that I have stated that I am asking if this could be achieved without using this permission...

Comment: sorry , i did not notice that

Answer (score 1):

We can use `ConnectivityManager#getNetworkCapabilities` and `NetworkCapablities#hasTransport` like this

```
ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkCapabilities caps = cm.getNetworkCapabilities(cm.getActivityNetwork());
boolean isMobile = caps.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR);
boolean isWifi = caps.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI);
```

Reference:

> **android.net.NetworkInfo**
> This class was deprecated in API level 29. Callers should instead use the ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback API
> to learn about connectivity changes, or switch to use
> ConnectivityManager#getNetworkCapabilities or
> ConnectivityManager#getLinkProperties to get information
> synchronously. Keep in mind that while callbacks are guaranteed to be
> called for every event in order, synchronous calls have no such
> constraints, and as such it is unadvisable to use the synchronous
> methods inside the callbacks as they will often not offer a view of
> networking that is consistent (that is: they may return a past or a
> future state with respect to the event being processed by the
> callback). Instead, callers are advised to only use the arguments of
> the callbacks, possibly memorizing the specific bits of information
> they need to keep from one callback to another.

Answer (score 0):

So my friend I have the same trouble as you but so far I came with a temporary fix I use the compileSdkVersion 29 not 30 as well as the targetSdkVersion 29 and my buildToolsVersion 28.0.3 and my app is loading fine.

Since this problem by me its coming due a third party library so till the fix the error I can not fix it alone, but I think with this temporary solution for now is quite well.

Comment: Compiling your application to API 29 does not deal with the issue...

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67705142/read-phone-state-permission-seems-to-be-actively-rejected-in-android-11