# Android App Keeps Crashing In Android Studio Emulator

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-emulator

I am making a navigation application using Mapbox (version 6.0.1) in android studio. Although my code does not give any errors, when I run it in the emulator (Pixel 3a API 30) the app keeps crashing. I have tried multiple emulators (Pixel 2 API 30 / Pixel_3a_API_30_x86 / Pixel 4 API 30) The app did not run at all in Pixel 2 API 30 and in other emulators it just crashed. I tried solving it but could not manage to. Could you help me locate the error? Thank you.

Manifest File:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.ens492runningapp">

    <!-- Using the location permission -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Ens492RunningApp">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

MainActivity.java File:

```java
package com.example.ens492runningapp;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.PersistableBundle;

import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.Mapbox;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    // Map view variables
    private MapView mapView;

    // Implementing all the constructors
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Mapbox.getInstance(this, getString(R.string.access_token)); // Getting the access token
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
        mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mapView.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mapView.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mapView.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        mapView.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        mapView.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory();
        mapView.onLowMemory();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mapView.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml File

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:mapbox="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <!-- Importing the map into the app -->
    <com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapView"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        mapbox:mapbox_cameraTargetLat = "37.7749"
        mapbox:mapbox_cameraTargetLng = "-122.4194"
        mapbox:mapbox_styleUrl = "mapbox://styles/mapbox/traffic-day-v2"
        mapbox:mapbox_cameraZoom = "12"
        />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Logcat:

```java
2021-05-10 15:35:59.147 9599-9599/com.example.ens492runningapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.ens492runningapp, PID: 9599
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.ens492runningapp/com.example.ens492runningapp.MainActivity}: java.lang.SecurityException: getDataNetworkTypeForSubscriber
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3449)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
     Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: getDataNetworkTypeForSubscriber
        at android.os.Parcel.createExceptionOrNull(Parcel.java:2373)
        at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:2357)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2340)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2282)
        at com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephony$Stub$Proxy.getNetworkTypeForSubscriber(ITelephony.java:8762)
        at android.telephony.TelephonyManager.getNetworkType(TelephonyManager.java:3021)
        at android.telephony.TelephonyManager.getNetworkType(TelephonyManager.java:2985)
        at com.mapbox.android.telemetry.TelemetryUtils.obtainCellularNetworkType(TelemetryUtils.java:148)
        at com.mapbox.android.telemetry.MapLoadEvent.<init>(MapLoadEvent.java:48)
        at com.mapbox.android.telemetry.MapEventFactory.buildMapLoadEvent(MapEventFactory.java:139)
        at com.mapbox.android.telemetry.MapEventFactory.createMapLoadEvent(MapEventFactory.java:56)
        at com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView.onCreate(MapView.java:276)
        at com.example.ens492runningapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:24)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8000)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7984)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3422)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

Comment: Maybe the version of MapBox you are using isn't compatible with Android 11(?) There a new limitations on reading the network type as mentioned e.g. in [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62692649/getnetworktype-in-android-11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62692649/getnetworktype-in-android-11) which is also about a `java.lang.SecurityException: getDataNetworkTypeForSubscriber`.

Comment: hey @MarkusKauppinen thank you for your reply, I will be looking into it.

Comment: hello again @MarkusKauppinen your comment was very helpful and it actually solved my problem. If you would add this as an answer to the question I will accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 4):

I'm guessing that are missing a security permission that you need to declare in your `AndroidManifest.xml`. Possibly `READ_PHONE_STATE`?

It also appears to be an issue with Mapbox itself, and will be resolved in an updated release: https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native-android/issues/425

The `READ_PHONE_STATE` might be a good workaround.

Comment: hey @shagberg thank you for your reply, however, I already tried using the READ_PHONE_STATE permission before posting the question but it still did not work.