# READ_PHONE_STATE permission seems to be actively rejected in Android 11

Tags: android, android-permissions

I have an application with following permissions in Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ANSWER_PHONE_CALLS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

I manually enabled all permissions through Settings in an Android 11 mobile. However, if I use `ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,(Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE))` to check if `READ_PHONE_STATE` permission has been granted, the result is always `PERMISSION_DENIED`.

I then used `ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, arrayOf(Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE), 102)`, which simply calls `onRequestPermissionsResult` with grant result `PERMISSION_DENIED` immediately.

I reproduced this on two Android 11 devices (one physical, one emulator), and I tried changing the package name, uninstalling and reinstalling the app etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured out what went wrong. One of the libraries I was including had this:

```
Library's Manifest
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"
    android:maxSdkVersion="29" />
```

and even though I defined this permission in my app manifest, the `maxSdkVersion` got into my app.

The solution is to remove the `maxSdkVersion` property in your app:

```
App's Manifest
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"
    tools:remove="android:maxSdkVersion" />
```

Comment: I had similar problem and my reason was mistyped permission name in Manifest. `adb shell dumpsys package <package name>` might help on debugging permissions