# Errors when launching app on Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, logcat

## Why am I receiving so many errors on logcat when I run my android app?

I am new to using android studio and also exploring the usage of maps on android apps. However, I ran into many issues in the process of launching the app as shown below.

Logcat:

There are many logs similar to these:

```
2021-10-19 17:22:32.931 3814-3997/com.example.sportbuddiesapp W/sportbuddiesap: Accessing hidden method Lcom/android/org/conscrypt/OpenSSLSocketImpl;->getAlpnSelectedProtocol()[B (greylist-max-q,core-platform-api, reflection, denied)
2021-10-19 17:22:32.931 3814-3997/com.example.sportbuddiesapp W/sportbuddiesap: Accessing hidden method Lcom/android/org/conscrypt/AbstractConscryptSocket;->getAlpnSelectedProtocol()[B (greylist-max-q, reflection, denied)
2021-10-19 17:26:06.379 3814-6367/com.example.sportbuddiesapp W/sportbuddiesap: Accessing hidden method Lcom/android/org/conscrypt/ConscryptEngineSocket;->setUseSessionTickets(Z)V (greylist-max-q,core-platform-api, reflection, denied)
2021-10-19 17:26:06.379 3814-6367/com.example.sportbuddiesapp W/sportbuddiesap: Accessing hidden method Lcom/android/org/conscrypt/OpenSSLSocketImpl;->setUseSessionTickets(Z)V (greylist-max-q,core-platform-api, reflection, denied)
2021-10-19 17:26:06.379 3814-6367/com.example.sportbuddiesapp W/sportbuddiesap: Accessing hidden method Lcom/android/org/conscrypt/AbstractConscryptSocket;->setUseSessionTickets(Z)V (greylist-max-q, reflection, denied)
2021-10-19 17:26:06.379 3814-6367/com.example.sportbuddiesapp W/sportbuddiesap: Accessing hidden method Lcom/android/org/conscrypt/ConscryptEngineSocket;->setHostname(Ljava/lang/String;)V (greylist-max-q,core-platform-api, reflection, denied)
2021-10-19 17:26:06.379 3814-6367/com.example.sportbuddiesapp W/sportbuddiesap: Accessing hidden method Lcom/android/org/conscrypt/OpenSSLSocketImpl;->setHostname(Ljava/lang/String;)V (greylist-max-q,core-platform-api, reflection, denied)
2021-10-19 17:26:06.379 3814-6367/com.example.sportbuddiesapp W/sportbuddiesap: Accessing hidden method Lcom/android/org/conscrypt/AbstractConscryptSocket;->setHostname(Ljava/lang/String;)V (greylist-max-q, reflection, denied)
2021-10-19 17:26:06.379 3814-6367/com.example.sportbuddiesapp W/sportbuddiesap: Accessing hidden method Lcom/android/org/conscrypt/OpenSSLSocketImpl;->setAlpnProtocols([B)V (greylist-max-q,core-platform-api, reflection, denied)
2021-10-19 17:26:06.379 3814-6367/com.example.sportbuddiesapp W/sportbuddiesap: Accessing hidden method Lcom/android/org/conscrypt/AbstractConscryptSocket;->setAlpnProtocols([B)V (greylist-max-q, reflection, denied)
2021-10-19 17:26:06.581 3814-6367/com.example.sportbuddiesapp W/sportbuddiesap: Accessing hidden method Lcom/android/org/conscrypt/OpenSSLSocketImpl;->getAlpnSelectedProtocol()[B (greylist-max-q,core-platform-api, reflection, denied)
2021-10-19 17:26:06.581 3814-6367/com.example.sportbuddiesapp W/sportbuddiesap: Accessing hidden method Lcom/android/org/conscrypt/AbstractConscryptSocket;->getAlpnSelectedProtocol()[B (greylist-max-q, reflection, denied)
```

and also one error:

```
2021-10-19 17:48:06.643 6803-6803/com.example.sportbuddiesapp E/TelemetryUtils: java.lang.SecurityException: getDataNetworkTypeForSubscriber
```

### Below are my project files

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.sportbuddiesapp">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"
        tools:ignore="CoarseFineLocation" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.SportBuddiesApp">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

MainActivity:

```
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;

import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.Mapbox;
import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private MapView mapView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Mapbox.getInstance(this, getString(R.string.mapbox_access_token));

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
        mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mapView.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mapView.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mapView.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        mapView.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        mapView.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory();
        mapView.onLowMemory();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mapView.onDestroy();
    }


}
```

Activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:mapbox="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        mapbox:mapbox_cameraTargetLat = "37.7749"
        mapbox:mapbox_cameraTargetLng = "-122.4194"
        />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Project Level Build.gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://mapbox.bintray.com/mapbox' }
    }
}


task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Module-Level build.gradle:

```
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdk 31

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.sportbuddiesapp"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 31
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}



dependencies {
    implementation ('com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:9.0.0'){
        exclude group: 'group_name', module: 'module_name'
    }
    implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-plugin-locationlayer:0.11.0'
    implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-telemetry:6.1.0'

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'

}
```

Comment: For `READ_PHONE_STATE` you need to take run time permissions from the user. Refer this https://stackoverflow.com/a/66039775/2462531

Answer (score 0):

I am getting the same errors because socket is not running and I guess you are getting this error because you don't have network_security_config.xml file. You can solve the problem by following the steps at this link: [Android 8: Cleartext HTTP traffic not permitted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45940861/android-8-cleartext-http-traffic-not-permitted/50834600#50834600).
Actually on the iOS side of the same application, when I changed the boolean allow arbitrary loads option from no to yes in the app transport security settings, the problem was resolved. transport security settings correspond to the network security config on the android side.
Remember, minSdk must be at least 24 for you to apply this solution.

PS: unfortunately the solution didn't work for me but I hope it helps you. I would appreciate if you let me know if it works here.