# SecurityException in android 11

Tags: android, android-studio, android-11, android-api-30

My android apk which was running nice on android 10 and previous version, but in android 11 my app getting crash as soon as I download it from google play store, It show only splash screen and then automatically app getting crash

I had given following permission manifest : camera, location, storage, phone

but it throwing security exception :

```
SecurityException: getDataNetworkTypeForSubscriber
```

and also not able to debug further because app getting crash immediately

Comment: Are you fetching network info in the splash screen or any where in the app?

Comment: not in splash screen ,some where in other activity

Comment: [GetNetworkType in Android 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62692649/getnetworktype-in-android-11) -  this answer might help you

Comment: thanks nitish  ,we tried your solution also ,still it give error in android studio, SecurityException: getDataNetworkTypeForSubscriber

Comment: Can you share the full logcat , ` SecurityException: getDataNetworkTypeForSubscriber` is not enough the detect the problem completely,

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` in `AndroidManifest.xml` file into **application** tag.

**android:requestLegacyExternalStorage** is give users more control over their files and limit file clutter