# App crash when using Scan Kit on Honor 50

Tags: java, android, kotlin, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-ml-kit

I'm using `com.huawei.hms:scan:1.3.2.300`

Device: Honor 50, Magic UI 4.2, Android version 11.

The following is the crash log：

> java.lang.SecurityException: getNetworkTypeForSubscriber 5 at
> android.os.Parcel.createExceptionOrNull(Parcel.java:2384) 6 at
> android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:2368) 7 at
> android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2351) 8 at
> android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2293) 9 at
> com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephony$Stub$Proxy.getNetworkTypeForSubscriber(ITelephony.java:8795)
> 10 at
> android.telephony.TelephonyManager.getNetworkType(TelephonyManager.java:3102)
> 11 at
> android.telephony.TelephonyManager.getNetworkType(TelephonyManager.java:3064)
> 12 at com.huawei.hms.mlkit.common.ha.d.b(HianalyticsLogUtils.java:68)
> 13 at
> com.huawei.hms.mlkit.common.ha.HianalyticsLogProvider.logEnd(HianalyticsLogProvider.java:6315)
> 14 at com.huawei.hms.ml.camera.g$a.a(HiAnalyticsThread.java:109) 15 at
> com.huawei.hms.ml.camera.g$a.handleMessage(HiAnalyticsThread.java:78)
> 16 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:109) 17 at
> android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:228) 18 at
> com.huawei.hms.ml.camera.g.run(HiAnalyticsThread.java:51)

Please help.

Comment: try this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/66039775/12543430

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

If the SDK version is later than or equal to Android R, you need to apply for `READ_PHONE_STATE` permissions dynamically in the code. Please check and try again.

The permission code is as follows:

```
    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {

            int res = checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE);
            if (res != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                requestPermissions(new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE}, 123);
            }

        }
    }

    private final static int REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS = 1003;

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS:
                if (grantResults[0] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "READ_PHONE_STATE Denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                } else {
                }
                stepAfterSplash();

                break;
            default:
                super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }
    }
```